# Distribution of $(X,Y,Z)$, $X=W(3)-W(1), Y=W(5)-W(2), Z=W(7)-W(4)$. (Brownian motion)

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Let $W(t),t \ge 0$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and let $(\mathcal F(t),t\ge0)$ be the natural filtration of $W$.
>
> Let $X=W(3)-W(1), Y=W(5)-W(2), Z=W(7)-W(4)$.
>
> I should determine the distribution of the random vector $(X,Y,Z)$.

---

My try:

$(X,Y,Z)$ is normally distributed because every component of it is normally distributed.

$\mu=(E[X],E[Y],E[Z])^T=(0,0,0)^T$

and

$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}C(X,X)&&C(X,Y)&&C(X,Z)\\C(Y,X)&&C(Y,Y)&&C(Y,Z)\\C(Z,X)&&C(Z,Y)&&C(Z,Z)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&&1&&0\\1&&3&&1\\0&&1&&3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: The reason that $(X,Y,Z)$ is jointly normal is not just because each component is normal (there exist random vectors where each component is normal but the joint distribution is not normal, as you can find via online searches). However, you can show in other ways that $(X,Y,Z)$ is jointly normal (e.g. try considering an arbitrary linear combination of $X,Y,Z$ and show this is normally distributed using properties of $W(t)$). Once you show that $(X,Y,Z)$ is joint normal, you just need to determine the mean vector and covariance matrix, which you look to have done correctly.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Two_normally_distributed_random_variables_need_not_be_jointly_bivariate_normal) for an example of a random vector where each component is normal but the joint distribution is not normal. Also see the discussions at [Is it possible to have a pair of Gaussian random variables for which the joint distribution is not Gaussian?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d)